# Matplotlib: Overlay scatter plot on top of step graph on same x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python and am working on implementing PageRank with the NetworkX library to create a world ranking for marathon swimmers.

I want to plot an athlete's ranking progression over time with a step chart (x=dates, y=ranks), and overlay dots that represent when they actually competed (x=race_dates, y=race_date_ranks). The values in the race_date_ranks list may or may not be in dates list (dates values are 7 days apart to improve runtime).

```
dates = ['06/03/2016', '06/10/2016', '06/17/2016', ... '07/14/2017']
ranks = [11, 11, 14,... 1]
race_dates = ['8/16/2016', '3/11/2017', '6/24/2017']
race_date_ranks = [1, 3, 1]
```

When I execute the following code, I get a weird chart where the race_dates and race_date_ranks are plotted separately and to the right of the step chart. Why is this happening??

```
plt.step(dates, ranks, where="post")
plt.plot(race_dates, race_date_ranks, "o")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("World Ranking")
plt.title(f"World Ranking Progression: {athlete_name}")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are plotting strings on the x-axis, not datetime objects. For matplotlib, your list of date strings is not different from a list like `[dog, cat, hedgehog]`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I just added two lines of code using datetime.strptime to convert them to a datetime object before plotting. I assumed that matplotlib was automatically doing this since the chart looked right, but turns out that's only because they happened to be in sequential order.

Comment: Don't worry, we all have been there. :) Good luck with your project.